# Issues in .Net interoperability with Borland C++

Tags: c#, interop, c++-cli, c++builder

I have a C# library which I want to use in Borland C++. The approach I have taken is to use mixed mode DLLs, i.e. to use C++/CLI as an intermediate between the C# library and Borland C++. I have created a sample HelloWorld program

### C# Library:

```
namespace Hello
{
   class HelloWorld
   {
      public void Display();
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
      }
   }
}
```

### C++/CLI:

I created a empty VC++ project and added the C# library as a reference to the C++/CLI project, which exports one function.I have changed the project settings to use /clr and changed the application type to DLL.

### Test.h

```
__declspec(dllexport) void DisplayHello();
```

### Test.cpp

```
#include "Test.h"
using namespace Hello;

__declspec(dllexport) void DisplayHello()
{
   HelloWorld ^ mHello = gcnew HelloWorld();
   mHello->Display();
}
```

### Borland C++:

I took the DLL generated by Visual Studio and used the IMPLIB utility provided by Borland to generate a LIB file that the Borland C++ compiler understands.

I use the generated lib file and the header file Test.h to build the BCB project, I have a function that calls DisplayHello

```
void CallDisplay()
{
   DisplayHello();//Application crashes here.
}
```

The weird thing that I have noticed is that when I remove

```
HelloWorld ^ mHello = gcnew HelloWorld();
mHello->Display();
```

the program works fine.

It throws a EExternal Exception "e0434352". There seems be some problem in the way I am using HelloWorld, I am unable to determine what could be causing the crash, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The error code 0xe0434352 is a CLR exception. When these occur at startup in my experience they are invariably an issue in locating assemblies. You can enable an [assembly binding log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) that would help you find out what can't be loaded. Anyway the .NET assembly should be in the .exe directory or registered in GAC if elsewhere.

If it is not an error loading assemblies, then try attaching the Windows Debugger (windbg) and using it's managed debugging to see precisely what the .NET exception is.